# Datalab Not Deploying

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Trying to deploy Datalab, but it never completes and the log files aren't createdto give any indication of the issue. I've tried multiple times and it creates the deploy VM (datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 in this case) and never deletes it, but the log file are always "Not Found" even hours later and looking in cloud storage browser there is not a bucket for the log files.

Updated...
Per Bradley's suggestion here is the last bit of output from the console:

```
Oct 15 23:12:29 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
Oct 15 23:17:09 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[5232]: Address 148.163.122.162 maps to we.love.servers.at.ioflood.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 15 23:17:09 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[5232]: Received disconnect from 148.163.122.162: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Oct 16 01:22:17 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[9155]: Did not receive identification string from 5.39.222.253
Oct 16 01:27:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[9315]: Address 148.163.122.162 maps to we.love.servers.at.ioflood.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 16 01:27:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[9315]: Invalid user admin from 148.163.122.162
Oct 16 01:27:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[9315]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Oct 16 01:27:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[9315]: Received disconnect from 148.163.122.162: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Oct 16 04:25:53 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[14926]: Did not receive identification string from 116.24.213.100
Oct 16 08:24:21 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[22485]: Did not receive identification string from 200.216.62.91
Oct 16 10:44:43 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[26879]: Connection closed by 85.25.43.94 [preauth]
Oct 16 12:51:21 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[30869]: Did not receive identification string from 117.4.112.76
Oct 16 12:51:25 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[30870]: Address 117.4.112.76 maps to localhost, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct 16 12:51:25 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[30870]: Invalid user support from 117.4.112.76
Oct 16 12:51:25 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[30870]: input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]
Oct 16 12:51:25 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[30870]: error: Received disconnect from 117.4.112.76: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Oct 16 13:21:43 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account james
Oct 16 13:21:55 datalab-deploy-main-20151015-23-10-51 sshd[31842]: Accepted publickey for james from 74.125.42.115 port 44312
```

It did work in another project, but ideally would like to access the data that we have in this project's Bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

If the deploy VM is still there, can you go to Developer Console, Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances, click on the VM, and click "Serial console output" at the end of the screen, and see anything useful there?

Also, if possible try a different project. Some old projects don't have all the dependency supported for Datalab.

Comment: Thanks @bradley. I updated the original question with the log output. And it did work in another project.